# FFmpeg потоковый ввод файлов

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg

Не могу передать mp4 файл в качестве входного файла через поток в ffmpeg процесс.
Сначала я преобразую видеофайл в массив байтов и передаю в метод PipeTest.

```cs
var vProcessor = new VideoProcessor();

var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\supertest\video.mp4");
var fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
stream.Close();

await vProcessor.PipeTest(fileBytes, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500), @"C:\supertest\PipeScreen.png");
```

Далее сам метод PipeTest

```cs
public async Task PipeTest(byte[] data, TimeSpan frameTime, string outFile)
{
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = _ffmpeg;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-i - -codec copy C:\\supertest\\qqq.mp4";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        proc.Start();

        proc.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(data);

        await proc.WaitForExitAsync();
}
```

ffmpeg в логах выдает ошибку

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002314aa4b1c0] stream 0, offset 0x30: partial file
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Помогите пожалуйста как исправить это.

Моя идея заключается в том чтобы передавать данные в ffmpeg в поток в StandartInput и получать обработанные им файлы в поток из StandartOutput.

Все выходные перерыл интернет, нигде нету решения.

Comment: `stream.Read` может прочитать меньше байт чем вы попросили. Это нормально на больших файлах. Думаю вы отдаёте в работу полупрочитанные данные.

Comment: Ещё одна ошибка проявится при обработке файлов больше *2GB*. `Stream.Read` не умеет читать так много из-за типа аргументов.

Comment: И последнее: зачем вы читать файл в память? Не лучше ли отдать его аргументом в `ffmpeg`? Тот сам будет его читать как ему удобно. И быстрее получится и памяти меньше нужно будет.

Comment: `var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\supertest\video.mp4");`

Comment: Попробовал ReadAllBytes та же ошибка.

Comment: [FFMpegCore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore), [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFMpegCore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp4 формат требует от кодека перемотки файла назад и вперед. Но fseek не сделать на пайпе. В этом контейнере не получится потоковая передача. Используйте другой контейнер (например mpegts) или другой способ передачи(http вместо пайпа). Или поменяйте и то и другое и используйте RTSP.

Comment: можете пожалуйста перечислить какие форматы позволяют перемотку

Comment: @StivenDiplet нужен нужен тот что не требует обращения к заголовку: mpegts и flv часто используются,  mkv работает если записан с флагом "для стрима"